# Using JSONPath to filter and get only specific properties as result?

Tags: jsonpath

Is it possible to use JSONPath to both filter and "select" properties to keep for the result.

For instance if we have the following JSON:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "age": 26,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "naist street",
        "city": "Nara",
        "postalCode": "630-0192"
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "iPhone",
            "number": "0123-4567-8888"
        },
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "0123-4567-8910"
        }
    ]
}
```

And we run a JSONPath like:

```
$.phoneNumbers[?(@.type=='iPhone')]
```

We would end up with the result:

```
[
  {
    "type": "iPhone",
    "number": "0123-4567-8888"
  }
]
```

Now lets say that what I actually want is the phonenumber.. so we could do this:

```
$.phoneNumbers[?(@.type=='iPhone')].number
```

Which would result in:

```
[
  "0123-4567-8888"
]
```

However.. the result that I would like to get would be:

```
[
  {
    "number": "0123-4567-8888"
  }
]
```

Notice how the actual JSON-object is returned and the property..
Is that possible to achive somehow using JSONPath?

Comment: Only with JSONPath? No! you need to do some kind of post-processing. `$.phoneNumbers[?(@.type=='iPhone')]` transforms to `$['phoneNumbers'][0]` and `$.phoneNumbers[?(@.type=='iPhone')].number` to `$['phoneNumbers'][0]['number']` . There is nothing in between.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know what property you're looking for (i.e. `number`), what you can do is to construct a new Json object with the property name and the returned value.

The actual implementation depends on what programming language you're using, but the pseudocode should look somewhat like this:

```
returnedList = json.find("$.phoneNumbers[?(@.type=='iPhone')].number")

initialize newJsonArray

foreach(returnedValue in returnedList):
  newJsonArray.add(newJsonObject("number", returnedValue))
```

An alternative way to tackle the problem in OOP languages is to use lambda functions to filter your Json objects instead of using Jsonpath filters. An example on how to do it in C# using `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
JArray jArray = new JArray(jObject.SelectToken("$.phoneNumbers").Where(x => x["type"].ToString() == "iPhone"));
```